# Dependency Injection for repository in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm new to spring boot and there are many things to learn. I've followed a tutorial on youtube and they teach how to create a DAO. My file structure looks like this.

[image]

The problem is when I used @Autowrite to inject the DataAccessI into my OrderService, the @Autowrite annotation noticed e an error. It confused me because I did the same thing as the instructor said but it won't work. These are some snippet of my code, hope that makes my problem be more clear:
OrderDAO

```
@Repository //specific kind of managed bean. useful when you doing data access
public class OrderDAO implements OrderAccessI {
    List<OrderModel> orders = new ArrayList<>();

    public OrderDAO() {
        orders.add(new OrderModel(0L,"000","Sky diving",15000f,1));
        orders.add(new OrderModel(1L,"001","Scuba diving",15000f,1));
        orders.add(new OrderModel(2L,"002","Shooting",15000f,1));
        orders.add(new OrderModel(3L,"003","Dying",15000f,1));
    }

    @Override
    public OrderModel getbyId(long id) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public List<OrderModel> getOrders() {
        return orders;
    }

    @Override
    public List<OrderModel> searchOrders(String searchTerm) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long addOne(OrderModel newOrder) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean deleteOne(long id) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public OrderModel updateOne(long idToUpdate, OrderModel updateOrder) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

SpringConfig

```
@Configuration //this is a Configuration file which the project must follow
public class SpringConfig {
    @Bean(name = "OrderService", initMethod = "init", destroyMethod = "destroy")
//    @RequestScope //live for only one page view
    @SessionScope //live for one session
    public OrderServiceI getOrderService() {
        return new OrderService();
    }
}
```

OrderService

```
public class OrderService implements OrderServiceI {

    public OrderAccessI ordersDAO;

    public OrderService() {
    }
    @Autowired
    public OrderService(OrderAccessI ordersDAO) {
        this.ordersDAO = ordersDAO;
    }


    @Override
    public void test() {
        System.out.println("OrderService is working");
    }

    @Override
    public List<OrderModel> getOrder() {
        return ordersDAO.getOrders();
    }

    @Override
    public void init() {
        System.out.println("Init method of OrderService");
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        System.out.println("Destroy method of OrderService");

    }
```

OrderRestController

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/orders")
public class OrderRestController {
    //if we create instance by calling class. if we have to change we have to change the line in this code (not cool)
    //    OrderService service;
    //    OrderService2 service;
    //solution create instance by using interface
    OrderServiceI service;
    @Autowired //go find this class and give me a new instance of it
    //recommend way: create a constructor
    public OrderRestController() {

    }

    @GetMapping
    public List<OrderModel> showAllOrder(Model model) {
        return service.getOrder();
    }
}
```

Thanks

I tried to create a new bean annotation in SpringConfig but it seems not working

```
    @Bean(name="OrdersDAO")
    public OrderAccessI getOrderDAO() {
        return new OrderDAO();
    }
```

Comment: Can you output the stacktrace of the error ?

Comment: I try not to mix `@Bean` and `@Autowired` for the same bean. In your case, add the DAO class as an argument into the Bean defintiion or Remove the bean declaration and add `@Service'  in your OrderService

Comment: @OlivierBoissé In the Inteliji, the Autowrite annotation noticed an error and it said that "Autowired members must be defined in valid Spring bean (Component|Service|...) ".
My project is still being able to build and run. but when I call the api, my browser displays a 500 error and a message: "There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500). Cannot invoke "com.pdt.topic2validation.Services.OrderServiceI.getOrder()" because "this.service" is null

Comment: @Archange I tried to add the service annotation into the OrderService and comment out the bean declaration in the SpringConfig like you suggested but the browser still have an error:"Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: java.lang.NullPointerException:"

Comment: The autowired IS on thé constrictor. Good practice then put thé service as an constructor argument and assign it to the class property.

Comment: @Archange thanks for your advice, I tried and it seem working now